# USB Partition Errors

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I have a USB key with 2 partitions on it that I'm trying to use on an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.  When I plug it in, one of the partitions mounts fine, the other doesn't appear.

I checked dmesg:

```
[  461.842961] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  461.982989] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=abcd, idProduct=1234
[  461.982994] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  461.982997] usb 1-2: Product: 1
[  461.983000] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: 1
[  461.983003] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1508051529112488889806
[  461.997749] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  461.997808] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[  461.998058] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  461.999035] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  462.999382] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     General  UDisk            5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  462.999642] scsi 3:0:0:1: Direct-Access     General  UDisk            5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  463.000018] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  463.000140] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096 512-byte logical blocks: (2.10 MB/2.00 MiB)
[  463.000276] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[  463.000280] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0b 00 80 08
[  463.000306] sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  463.000465] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  463.000471] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  463.000594] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdc] 7794688 512-byte logical blocks: (3.99 GB/3.72 GiB)
[  463.000781] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  463.000785] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[  463.000982] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  463.000986] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  463.004150]  sdb:
[  463.007180]  sdc:
[  463.008099] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  463.008537] sd 3:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  463.244222] FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

So I ran fsck:

```
~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdc
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/sdc: 4 files, 2649/972432 clusters
```

After running this, I plugged the drive back in to the same results.  I opened the disk in GParted, and I saw one of the partitions along with a warning on the drive:

```
plain floppy: device "/dev/sdc" busy (Resource temporarily unavailable):
Cannot initialize '::'
mlabel: Cannot initialize drive
```

The weird thing is, sdc shows up in GParted, but sdb doesn't.  I know sdb is read-only, but would that prevent it from showing in GParted?  Also, is the sdc partition working properly given the warnings in GParted?

Comment: It sounds like you have no partition on sdc. Your fsck on sdc should have given an error, as you have to run it on a partition like sdc1. But it worked. And sdc is being seen as a "superfloppy" type drive. Almost all tools expect partitions not an old floppy drive that your directly read. Does this work? mount superfloppy fat formatted.
`mount -t vfat /dev/sdc /media/disk/` You may need sudo and create /media/disk as mount point first.

Comment: That does work, the weird thing about this is when I list the directory it shows a 'System Volume Information' directory that I don't recall putting on this disk....

Comment: Backup everything on it, and create a partition table and at least one partition. Format it with whatever format you want and copy data back. Then normal partition tools & utilities will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by formatting the partition as cleared (the last option of gparted), apply changes and then create a new partition table as msdos and apply changes again. After that you only have to create a new partition in the free space.

I hope this help you